# Genymotion Devices crash on start

Tags: android, virtualbox, virtualization, android-virtual-device, genymotion

I downloaded a device long months ago, which is working fine. I tried to download new devices but they were crashing on the start, I got a message saying that my PC doesn't support virtualization. I checked my BIOS and found that the virtualization option is enabled. I updated Genymotion but it's still the same problem. 
My virtualBox version is 4.13.12.

thanks

Comment: What is your OS? If Windows, is HyperV started? do you have any other hypervisor running?

Comment: yes i'm on windows. i don't use Hyper-V so i don't know if it could be started without me. the problem is that the old virtual device is running normally but any new device will crash at starting

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember - some new devices could require newer versions of Genymotion. Try to update your Genymotion first.

Comment: @ImadDZ sorry, didn't noticed that. Could you type the full error message?

Comment: it's in french, it says that it's impossible to connect to the virtual device , plus a link https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support?chapter=collapse-nostart#faq , i did what was said but it didn't work.

Comment: i send them the output but they didn't reply :/